# How do I improve performance of Core Data object insert on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, performance, core-data

I'm trying to import a large amount of data into a core data store on the iPhone. I'm using a SQLite backing for the core data store. It seems to be taking way longer than I would expect it to. I've trimmed down the routines so that it is basically just attempting to a fetch an object (to see if it already exists) and then create a new object if it doesn't (they never do since I am importing data). The fetching isn't the time consuming part, though. It's the creation of the objects. Basically, the offending code is:

```
MobileObject *newObject = (MobileObject *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:objDesc inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

I've noticed that on the simulator, it is fairly quick at the start with about 100 objects created a second. It slows down though and by the time five thousand objects are created it's almost 2 seconds for 100 objects and by the time ten thousand objects are created, it's 4 seconds per 100 objects. The whole group of 21000 objects takes more than 10 minutes. That is with all the actual useful code taken out (that's just a fetch and an object create). And it's much much slower on the actual device (by maybe 4 times as much).

What I don't understand is why core data starts off fast but then begins to slow down. I've tried both with index and no indexes on my data. I've tried creating my own autorelease pool which I periodically drain in my loop. I've tried saving after every object creation. I've tried waiting until the end to save. But no matter what I do, the performance still seems miserable. Is it just that slow to add a new object to a core data store with a few thousand objects in it? Any suggestions?

Comment: I should comment that actually I think the fetches are the ones taking up a significant amount of time. I suppose that makes sense since as the store gets bigger, there are more objects to search through.

Comment: As an aside, the cast in your sample code above is unnecessary.  `-insertNewObjectForEntity...` returns an `id` and therefore does not and should not be cast.

Comment: Creating a huge database this way can be incredibly slow if you wait until the end to save. Generally I save after every few thousand new objects, have not experimented to find the optimum frequency.

Comment: Would you still like this question answered?

Comment: @Mike have you find solution for your problem. I have exactly the same problem. I also tried with adding normalizedText attribute to my model object, so I can improve search performance but it is still slow after import of 2000 items...

Answer (score 2):

It can be quite speedy but it depends on what you are doing.  As others have suggested you should be looking at Instruments and finding the actual hotspot.  Also posting the actual import code would help to identify the issue.

Comment: For me, I *am* using Instruments and it tells me _sharedIMPL_addObjectToSet_core takes 99% of the time - in turn key value observer of NSObject takes 50%, and _PF_ManagedObject_DidChangeValueForKeywithSetMutation
takes the other 50%. I am connecting a many-to-many relationship between thousands of "Sentence" entities - these are translations of each other. Even after trying some optimizations, the slow culprit is really the relationship "insert" which likely goes on behind the scenes in CoreData. I just get the feeling that this would get at least 50% faster if using direct sqlite :-P

Comment: SQLite is faster than Core Data.  Core Data is not going to be the fastest, it is the most maintainable.  As for Instruments, hide system libraries, flatten recursion and invert the call tree.  Then see what is on top that is **YOUR** code.  That is what you need to fix.  When you find the method that is yours, double click on it and Instruments will show you what is slow *inside* of that method.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I dug down to my function which contained a loop of a couple hundred thousands of many-to-many relationship for just one entity - yes those sentences are translations of each other. I was thinking the intermediate NSDictionaries that I used for source data was slow with indexing and I did some optimization there, but Instruments clearly showed that the problem is not about NSDictionary, just the inside insert operations. Which really uses sqlite in the end. The last time I tried Core Data, I also got problem with too slow performance and went with Sqlite only.

Comment: If you are doing a couple hundred thousand many-to-many relationships off one entity then you have a design problem or a pre-population problem.  With Core Data being an object graph and SQLite being a database, SQLite is always going to be faster at persisting.  The purpose of Core Data is not speed to disk as I said before.  Wrong tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Instruments. Don't you save after inserting every single object? Actually, more insert-related code and scheme may be very useful.