# Core Data Efficiency

Tags: iphone, core-data, processing-efficiency

Is it overkill to store 4 types of attributes into a 32-bit int within Core Data?
Or should I simply create a separate attribute for each of them? (will use logic operators to set/get).

I plan to add a new entity to an existing object which will contain anywhere from 200-400 items with about 14 attributes (including an 'index' attribute for ordering purposes). Only one set will be operated on or viewed at any time.

I will need to maintain undo support (referencing [How do I improve performance of Core Data object insert on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559599/core-data-on-iphone-and-performance))

I may be able to ween this down to about 8 attributes if I store several attributes into a single field. Barring the searchability issue, will I be saving appreciable space?

Also, is it unreasonable to store a set of 400 objects in a growing list of items which will grow at a rate of about 1-3 per week?

I hear some people storing thousands of items in core data so perhaps I am being paranoid.  I suppose in the long-run I will need to provide an export archive option, perhaps to iCloud.

Comment: Just to confirm. You can store thousands of items in Core Data SQLite persistent store. It works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're saying you have 400 objects with 14 attributes, which you could either store as separate integers, or combine into fewer 32-bit (4-byte) values?

400 x 14 x 4 bytes = 22,400 bytes

That's not very much space at all. If you cut that in half, you're saving 11K, which will probably be dwarfed by the size of the extra code you'll be generating to encode and decode these values.

**But don't take my word for it:** write a small test program that stuffs values into Core Data, then run it under the profiler to see what happens.

You can also read up on SQLite and how it stores values, since that's what Core Data is using under the hood.

My gut says you're being paranoid and your bit twiddling code won't help much. Worse, it will be a great way to introduce really subtle bugs when you forget that you are shifting with sign extension. (And I love writing bit-twiddling code!)

Comment: Thanks! Writing a test program is a good idea. A Pragmatic Programmer tip comes to mind... "Don’t Assume It—Prove It". I will check out SQL Lite docs as well.